# How to find out what happens when I use Monoid for Map in scalaz

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalaz

1. How can I find all instances of `Monoid`. For example, how to know if there is a `Monoid` instance for `Map` in scalaz ?
   And if yes, where it is in the source code.
   I've tried the following without success

   ```
   @ implicitly[Monoid[Map[_, _]]]
   Main.scala:1146: could not find implicit value for parameter e: scalaz.Monoid[Map[_, _]]
   implicitly[Monoid[Map[_, _]]]
             ^
   Compilation Failed
   ```
2. How can i see what happens (implicit conversions, …) when I execute code from the REPL, like

   ```
   Map("a", 1) |+| Map("a", 1)
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no way to find all the instances of a type class.

   Specifically for `Map` it depends on the type of the values, because a `Map[K, V]` monoid instance needs a `Semigroup[V]` instance.

   You can find the code for `Map`'s `Monoid` in [`scalaz.std.map`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Map.scala#L120-L136).
2. You can see the implicit conversions using reflection :

   ```
   import scalaz.std.map._
   import scalaz.std.anyVal._
   import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._

   import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

   showCode(reify { Map("a" -> 1) |+| Map("a" -> 1)  }.tree)
   // `package`.monoid.ToSemigroupOps(
   //   Predef.Map.apply(Predef.ArrowAssoc("a").->(1)))
   //   (map.mapMonoid(Predef.this.DummyImplicit.dummyImplicit, anyVal.intInstance))
   //   .|+|(Predef.Map.apply(Predef.ArrowAssoc("a").->(1)))
   ```

   The Scalaz implicits at work are :

   - The syntax conversion `ToSemigroupOps` to add the `|+|` operation to `Map`.
   - The `Monoid` instance for `Map[String, Int]` which uses the `Semigroup[Int]` instance.

Comment: Is there an implicit conversion without using scalaz?